# Algorithm for selecting the differents pair

Tags: algorithm, function

May be somebody can help me with it.
So, I have a set of pairs x0-y0, x1-y1, etc.
And always x[i]<y[i]. Thus I need a function (or algorithm) for every pair, so
F(x[i],y[i]) = result[i],  and each result for a particular pair must be an integer **unique** value.

Comment: `result[i] = i`? is definitively unique. And as you don't specify any conditions on how `x, y` relate to `result`, it fulfills all your conditions ...

Comment: I'm just looking for this feature. It should be similar to an integer hash function. The pairs can be repeated, for example:
{1, 10} = r1
{17,63} = r2
(5,28} = r3
...
{17,63} = r3 again
I want it to be calculated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `M = max(y) - min(y) + 1`, then use the formula:

```
F(x, y) = x * M + y
```

Remarks:

- You don't have to use the exact maximum and minimum, you can use an upperbound and a lowerbound, `M = U - L + 1` with `U` larger than all y and `L` smaller than all `y`;
- Of course you could do it the other way around instead, with `K = max(x) - min(x) + 1`, and `F(x, y) = y * K + x`;
- When using a finite integer type, be careful with overflow, for instance if x and y both have values larger than 46340, then F(x, y) won't fit in a 32-bit signed integer.

Comment: Yes, but in practice with a finite integer type, you must be careful not to overflow (for example by using a larger int type to compute F). For example, with a 32 bit int type, you will overflow if there's some x and some y greater than 46340 (because then max(x)>=46341 so for the pair with the "large" y, F(x, y) >= 46341*46341 > 2^31

Comment: Also, I think you're off by one. If your input is (0, 10), (1, 0) then M=10, and both pairs hash to 10.

Comment: @PaulHankin x and y always > 0 and the ceil of y is 400k only. But you are right, sure